# Unable to send UDP packet via native NodeJS UDP API

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, udp, dhcp

Together with friends I develop a DHCP server, in order to get my hands dirty with networking, which always been my Achilles heel.

I'm able to receive and parse basic DHCP packets, but I can't send a response. To send the packet I use [socket.send](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_send_msg_offset_length_port_address_callback), with 255.255.255.255 as a destination and 68 as the port. I correctly get the callback of this function called (with no error), which should indicate that the packet has been sent, but I can't see the UDP packet outgoing in the wireshark. The issue occurs on a multitude of laptops and NodeJS versions.

Sourcecode: https://github.com/MarcinGrzeszczak/Kricco/tree/dhcpdecline

The code that sends the packet: https://github.com/MarcinGrzeszczak/Kricco/blob/dhcpdecline/index.js

Steps to reproduce:

1. `npm i` to install dependencies, and then `npm start` to deploy the server. *(WARNING, your OS might already occupy the port in this case you need to kill the process that does it. There might also be case when OS tells you that this port is restricted, the quick workaround is to run npm start with root privileges, I haven't found an elegant solution for this as for now)*.
2. Set up a hotspot on your machine.
3. Connect a device to your newly hosted wifi network.
4. Quickly connect wireshark to your wifi interface
5. You should be able to see incomming dhcp packets, but Kricco won't be able to send a response

Comment: "_To send the packet I use socket.send, with 255.255.255.255 as a destination and 68 as the port._" You send a response to the unicast address that DHCP assigns using the MAC address of the destination as the layer-2 address. It is only if the client sets the broadcast flag do you send to the broadcast address. This is all detailed in _[RFC 2131, Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2131). If you want to write a DHCP server, then you need to strictly follow the RFC.

Comment: It is a common myth that all DHCP messages are sent via broadcast. The client uses broadcast, but the DHCP server almost always uses unicast at layer-3, and always at layer-2).

Comment: @RonMaupin Actually I've tried to just send an empty UDP packet as a response, but it's not visible as outgoing in the wireshark, so the issue seems to be lower than the DHCP protocol itself.

Comment: Is it possible to check whether there's a packet outgoing but not arriving to the place where wireshark is attached to?

Comment: Try sending the response to the unicast address assigned by the DHCP server using the MAC address received by the DHCP server. You will need to do that to make the DHCP server work, anyway.

Comment: What is your wireshark filter?  Also, following @RonMaupin once you assign an IP address, you need to add it to the ARP table and then send the response to the assigned IP.